# Реализация графического приложения в PyQt5

Tags: pyqt5, qt-designer, python-3.6

Что нужно использовать в PyQt5 и QtDesigner для реализации графического приложения? Какие советы можете дать? Можно ли закинуть рисунок как статическую часть графической части? И дорисовать канаты и вагонетки, у которых изменяется длина и положение соответственно, как динамическую часть? Можно ли прикрепить их к координатной сетке?
[image: Пример приложения]

Comment: да, все это можно сделать

Comment: Alexander Chernin, это все делать с помощью класса QGraphicScene? Или что-то другое использовать. Где брать координатную сетку?